# I was making a calculator using c++ but the compiler is giving an error

Tags: c++

I am a brand new to c++. Recently I had completed all the loops(which was given in my online tutorial).

 I decided to create a calculator which would first take a function from the user as

1. A (for sum)

   S (for subtraction)

   M (for multiply)

I am sure that you will help me. But the compiler is giving some error. (DEV-c++). I am in a great trouble.

```
//The program begins here
#include <iostream>

#include <define.h>    //This is my own header file
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){


int x;


int y;


char z;


char a,s,m,d,c;
    do 
    {cout<<"Enter the function below :"<<NEWLINE;
    cout<<"Following are the possible functions:  "<<"1."<<"a-add"<<NEWLINE<<"2."<<"s-subtract"<<NEWLINE<<"3. "<<"m-multiply"<<NEWLINE<<"4. "<<"d-divide"<<NEWLINE;
cin>>z;
while (z!=c);   
    }
    if (z=a){    /*here is the error place. it tells to give a "while" `before '(' token. (but I dont know why)...`*/
      cout<<"Please enter your first digit to be added"<<NEWLINE;
      cin>>x;
        cout<<"Your first digit is "<<x<<NEWLINE<<"Please enter 2nd digit to be added";
        cin>>y;
        cout<<"You entered "<<y<<"."<<"The sum of"<<x<<" and "<<y<<" is "<<x+y;

    else if (z=s){        /*Here It tells me that "else without a previous if".             //BUT I have given IF before this.*/
        cout<<"Please enter the first digit "<<NEWLINE;
        cin>>x;
        cout<<"You entered "<<x<<" Please enter 2nd digit: "<<NEWLINE;
        cin>>y;
        cout<<"Your equation is"<<x<<"-"<<y<<"="<<x-y;
    }
    else if(z=m){
        cout<<"Enter the first digit"<<NEWLINE;
        cin>>x;
        cout<<"Your 1st digit is"<<x<<". Enter the 2nd digit"<<NEWLINE;
        cin>>y;
        cout<<"Your equation is"<<x<<"+"<<y<<"="<<x+y;
    }
    }
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: They are given as comments where the error is coming. Please If you can then help me

Comment: You have many errors in your source. For example, `if (z=s)` has problems in two different ways (none of which is detectable by the compiler). Have you ever worked with a language with c-like syntax before?

Comment: When posting questions about build errors, always include the *complete* and *unedited* build log in the question body, then mark out (with comments, no formatting) in the provided source (similar to what you have done). Also, please enable more warnings when building, they will tell you things that ate syntactically correct but that might cause other problems later (run-time crashes, undefined behaviors, using assignment instead of comparison etc.).

Comment: The placement of brackets is significant but much easier to get right if you get a modern editor that can indent the code for you.

Comment: I must ask, what is `NEWLINE` defined as? You could have used `endl` instead. If you simply have `#define NEWLINE endl` that's allowed, but it does remind me of the first editions of Visual C++, which had completely unnecessary things like `#define VOID void`

Comment: @MrLister I suspect he has a nonconforming compiler from the 90s

Comment: For fun: this is C++ **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01157303785c7f15)**

Answer (score 5):

Your while is misplaced. This is what the compiler tells you:

```
test.cpp|23 col 8| error: expected ‘while’ before ‘(’ token
||      if (z = a) { // here is the error place. it tells to give a "while" before '(' token. (but I dont know why)...
```

So, fix it:

```
do {
    cout << "Enter the function below :" << NEWLINE;
    cout << "Following are the possible functions:  "
         << "1."
         << "a-add" << NEWLINE << "2."
         << "s-subtract" << NEWLINE << "3. "
         << "m-multiply" << NEWLINE << "4. "
         << "d-divide" << NEWLINE;
    cin >> z;
} while (z != c);
```

Many more issues:

```
if (z = a) { // here is the error place. it tells to give a "while" before '(' token. (but I dont know why)...
```

Should be `z==a`

---

```
    else if (z = s)
```

should probably be `} else if (z==s)` ...

---

Many more things are wrong. `a`, `s`, `m`, `c` are never initialized... Did you mean `'a'`, `'s'` etc.?

My best bet, which - at least - compiles:

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <define.h> //This is my own header file
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    char z = ' ';

    do {
        std::cout << "Enter the function below :"
            << "\n";
        std::cout << "Following are the possible functions:  "
            "1. a-add\n"
            "2. s-subtract\n"
            "3. m-multiply\n"
            "4. d-divide\n";
        std::cin >> z;
        if (z == 'a') { // here is the error place. it tells to give a "while" before '(' token. (but I dont know why)...
            std::cout << "Please enter your first digit to be added"
                << "\n";
            int x, y;
            std::cin >> x;
            std::cout << "Your first digit is " << x << "\n"
                << "Please enter 2nd digit to be added";
            std::cin >> y;
            std::cout << "You entered " << y << "."
                << "The sum of" << x << " and " << y << " is " << x + y;
        } else if (z == 's') { /*Here It tells me that "else without a previous if".             //BUT I have given IF before
                               this.*/
            std::cout << "Please enter the first digit "
                << "\n";
            int x, y;
            std::cin >> x;
            std::cout << "You entered " << x << " Please enter 2nd digit: "
                << "\n";
            std::cin >> y;
            std::cout << "Your equation is" << x << "-" << y << "=" << x - y;
        } else if (z == 'm') {
            std::cout << "Enter the first digit"
                << "\n";
            int x, y;
            std::cin >> x;
            std::cout << "Your 1st digit is" << x << ". Enter the 2nd digit"
                << "\n";
            std::cin >> y;
            std::cout << "Your equation is" << x << "+" << y << "=" << x + y;
        }
    } while (z != 'c');

    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And a, s and m are not even initialised. The OP probably meant 'a', etc.

Comment: @MrLister I was still diving into the mess :) But yeah, many more things wrong. I'll update in a few

Comment: You solved my half problem. One onother problem is there its giving an error as "21 2 C:\Users\shivam\Desktop\c++\Calculator.cpp [Error] expected unqualified-id before 'if'  "

Comment: @ShivamProgramer http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/235921fc0941871d - Also, I would like to remind you we're not obliged to "solve your problem". I fact, you are obliged to create problems one at a time and fix them before you have a snippet of code with more errors than there are crickets in a plague.

Comment: Please tell what were the errors

Comment: @ShivamProgramer Please read the answer.

Comment: After exactly 1 year and 8 months, I really realized how stupid were I..lol